# xml loading with specific filter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an XML format like this..

```
<ROOT>
    <bookstore>
        <Name>XXXXXX</BUNIT>
    </bookstore>
    <book>
        <ID>000000000000001001</ID>
        <title>Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>        
    </book>
    <book>
        <ID>000000000000001002</ID>
        <title>Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>        
    </book>
    <book>
        <ID>000000000000001003</ID>
        <title>Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>        
    </book>
    <book>
        <ID>000000000000001004</ID>
        <title>Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>        
    </book>
</ROOT>
```

Now I want to load only single node of book with "ID" without loop.
I have tried some this like this..
we will get full node of book(first item id=000000000000001001) with the below line

```
_nodeList = objxml.SelectSingleNode("//book/")
```

but I will give ID to filter like below code.

```
_nodeList = objxml.SelectSingleNode("//book/ID['000000000000001001']")
```

and I need full book node with that particular ID.

Comment: You have an error in your XML, you aren't closing `<Name>` and whats `</BUNIT>`?

Comment: This `<Name>XXXXXX</BUNIT>` is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If i've understood the question correctly, you want to select a book element by the child element `ID` value?

If this is the case you can use a very simple LINQ query to return the book node by ID (assuming you have corrected your XML first):

```
var book = from n in xml.Descendants("ROOT").Elements("book")
                       where n.Element("ID").Value == "000000000000001001"
                       select n;
```

You could then project the values to anonymous types and cast the query to a list to enumerate the results:

```
var book = (from n in xml.Descendants("ROOT").Elements("book")
            where n.Element("ID").Value == "000000000000001001"
            select new
            {
                ID = (string)n.Element("ID").Value,
                Title = (string)n.Element("title").Value,
                Author = (string)n.Element("author").Value,
                Year = (string)n.Element("year").Value,
                Price = (string)n.Element("price").Value
            }).ToList();
```

Which will give output such as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var book = onjxml.SelectSingleNode("//ROOT/book[ID='000000000000001003']")
```

Comment: +1 You don't need the ROOT, though, with the double slash.